# Sustainsys Saml2 library for ASP.NET MVC with FormsAuthentication

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I have integrated Sustainsys Saml2 library with my ASP.NET MVC 5 website. I am able to get the SSO Login done by OneLogin, but when I am trying to redirect to my [Authorize] pages (Dashboard), always the app redirect to Login page. 
I tried to create my externalLoginCallBack method to be called after ACS method and set the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, but it didn't work.

The `.ASPXAUTH` always is empty after call [Authorize] methods.
Have you guys seen this issue before? 
I really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What nuget package are you using? Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc? Sustainsys.Saml2.Owin?

Comment: I am using Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc V1. I couldn't use V2, because the dependencies issues.

Comment: Also, I cannot see HttpContext.User.Identity.Name after ACS redirect to another controller. Maybe this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Saml2Controller in the nuget package calls the `SessionAuthenticationModule` to set a session cookie. It is more flexible than the FormsAuthenticationModule as it allows full claims identities. But otherwise they work the same.

Ensure that you have loaded the SessionAuthenticationModule in the web.config.